# temporaly hide QCandlestickSeries in Python

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, candlestick-chart, qtcharts

How to temporarily hide QCandlestickSeries on the chart? I tried:

```py
....

self._cs = QtChart.QCandlestickSeries()
self._ls = QtChart.QLineSeries()

...

self._cs.hide() # does not work
self._ls.hide() # work

...
```

[edit] here is example of code where is described problem:

```py
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

# data
t = [1557723420.0, 1573102560.0, 1577163360.0]
v = [258, 259, 253]

# candlestick series
candlestick = QtChart.QCandlestickSeries()

# line series
line = QtChart.QLineSeries()

# add data
for _t, _v in zip(t, v):
    _open = _v + 10
    _high = _v + 30
    _low = _v - 20
    _close = _v if _v%2 else _high - 5
    _time = QtCore.QDateTime(datetime.date.fromtimestamp(_t))
    candlestick.append(QtChart.QCandlestickSet(_open, _high, _low, _close, _time.toMSecsSinceEpoch() ))
    line.append(_time.toMSecsSinceEpoch(), _v )

# main window
window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

# axises
axis_x = QtChart.QDateTimeAxis()
axis_x.setFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
axis_x.setTitleText("Date")
axis_x.setLabelsAngle(-90)

axis_y = QtChart.QValueAxis()
axis_y.setTitleText("Ratio")

# chart
chart = QtChart.QChart()
chart.addAxis(axis_x, QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
chart.addAxis(axis_y, QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
chart.addSeries(candlestick)
chart.addSeries(line)
chart.setAxisX(axis_x, candlestick)
chart.setAxisX(axis_x, line)
chart.setAxisY(axis_y, candlestick)
chart.setAxisY(axis_y, line)

# chart view
chart_view = QtChart.QChartView()
chart_view.setChart(chart)
chart_view.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
window.setCentralWidget(chart_view)
window.show()

# hide
candlestick.hide() # <- does not work
line.hide() # work

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I use QLineSeries and method hide, that is work correctly. 
I use PyQT5.

Comment: please provide a [mre] and what is your PyQt5 or PySide2 version?

Comment: I edited original article, and sorry for Lorem ipsum text - fill only.

Answer (score 2):

That is a bug that has not been solved yet: [QTBUG-63358](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-63358).

A possible workaround is to remove the series from the chart to create the same behavior of the `hide()` method, in the case of the `show()` method, the series must be added to the chart:

```py
import datetime
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtChart

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    # data
    t = [1557723420.0, 1573102560.0, 1577163360.0]
    v = [258, 259, 253]

    # candlestick series
    candlestick = QtChart.QCandlestickSeries()

    # line series
    line = QtChart.QLineSeries()

    # add data
    for _t, _v in zip(t, v):
        _open = _v + 10
        _high = _v + 30
        _low = _v - 20
        _close = _v if _v % 2 else _high - 5
        _time = QtCore.QDateTime(datetime.date.fromtimestamp(_t))
        candlestick.append(
            QtChart.QCandlestickSet(
                _open, _high, _low, _close, _time.toMSecsSinceEpoch()
            )
        )
        line.append(_time.toMSecsSinceEpoch(), _v)

    # main window
    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

    # axises
    axis_x = QtChart.QDateTimeAxis()
    axis_x.setFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    axis_x.setTitleText("Date")
    axis_x.setLabelsAngle(-90)

    axis_y = QtChart.QValueAxis()
    axis_y.setTitleText("Ratio")

    # chart
    chart = QtChart.QChart()
    chart.addAxis(axis_x, QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
    chart.addAxis(axis_y, QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
    chart.addSeries(candlestick)
    chart.addSeries(line)
    chart.setAxisX(axis_x, candlestick)
    chart.setAxisY(axis_y, candlestick)

    chart.setAxisX(axis_x, line)
    chart.setAxisY(axis_y, line)

    # chart view
    chart_view = QtChart.QChartView()
    chart_view.setChart(chart)
    chart_view.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
    window.setCentralWidget(chart_view)
    window.show()

    state = True

    def on_timeout():
        global state
        state = not state

        line.setVisible(state)
        serie = candlestick
        if state:
            # add == show
            chart.addSeries(serie)
            chart.setAxisX(axis_x, serie)
            chart.setAxisY(axis_y, serie)
            # workaround for repaint
            chart.resize(chart.size() + QtCore.QSizeF(1, 1))
            chart.resize(chart.size() - QtCore.QSizeF(1, 1))
        else:
            # remove == hide
            chart.removeSeries(serie)

    timer = QtCore.QTimer(interval=1000, timeout=on_timeout)
    timer.start()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```